# What's geometric about a "geometric progression"?

Tags: terminology, geometric-progressions

An arithmetic progression is $a+0b, a+1b, a+2b, ..., a+nb$

A geometric progression is $ab^0, ab^1, ab^2, ..., ab^n$.

Multiplication is arithmetic, so why is a geometric progression not also an "arithmetic" progression?

A line being extended be iteratively adding a constant length is a geometric construction, so why is an arithmetic progression not also a "geometric" progression?

Comment: It appears to be an exact duplicate of Q820680 on math. It's really not a question of the Use of English.

Comment: Because there's a very nice geometric visualization, I suppose. This one is for $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$ specifically: https://images.hive.blog/p/JvFFVmatwWHVQPjDcGkFxELgGtwNAntRtiqDuEyy8Rghsyf7R2YFZ82HfFY76VyvBMgXavpaUh2DcFSWCA3S1euK7XxZRas1jCPxUek9TxQb822EeHgUB39jErdxPsoTjNX2oczCyL?format=match&mode=fit&width=768

Comment: link to the above mentioned [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820680/arithmetic-and-geometric-sequences-where-does-their-name-come-from) and do look at the linked questions therein.

Comment: None of the linked answers are satisfactory. This is an excellent question.

Comment: This has been migrated once already, but likely a better place to ask is on the [History of Science & Mathematics forum](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/). I agree with John Douma that the interpretations of geometric series by geometry (while nice) do not address why they were originally given these names. But C. Oliveira's post on the linked question does provide some good research on the matter.